# Same server, same file, different mime types

Tags: coldfusion, mime-types

Same application running on two different servers (dev/prod). The servers are running the same version of pretty much everything as far as I can tell (CF, Java, IIS, etc).

On development I upload a specific Word doc and ColdFusion identifies it as `application/msword` and on prod it's identified as `application/x-tika-msoffice`.

I'm trying to diagnose why. My fix is to allow the `application/x-tika-msoffice` mime type in my uploads, but still, what can cause it to be different. If there are some specific server settings I need to check please let me know, but everything I can think of seems the same between prod and dev.

Comment: Does the MIME Type for .doc in IIS match in dev and prod?

Comment: Yes it does. They both say application/msword

Comment: There are several similar entries in Adobe's bugbase dating back to at least 2014. Is the file a .doc or .docx? Has it ever touched OpenOffice?

Comment: I cannot speak to how the file was generated, but just based on the MIME type I was going to assume so. I've sent a request to the person who gave me the file to see. For what it's worth when I inspect the file in Windows it says application/msword.

Comment: I checked with the user who had the file and he said he saved as a 97-03 file and was using Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 2):

The MIME type is **sent by the browser** so that is probably explains the difference you are seeing. Perhaps on development you have Office installed and on the production server you hopefully do not.

You should never use the MIME type to determine if a file should be uploaded for this reason -- instead **always use the file extension**. This mime type can easily be *spoofed* and is thus pointless to rely upon for validation.

CF10+ allows you to specify a file extension list in the `accept` attribute of the `cffile` tag. It also adds the `strict` attribute and defaults it to `true` which does a server side MIME type inspection (essentially the same as running [`fileGetMimeType()`](http://cfdocs.org/filegetmimetype) but even with `strict=true` you still cannot rely upon this file inspection, extensions are more important (do both).

Comment: I don't understand your first part. I'm using my same machine to upload the file (same browser) and ColdFusion gets the MIME type server side from reading the temp file. So unless the MIME type is edited in transit by the browser and then added as meta data to the temp file on the server, I'm not sure how that is possible. Are you saying the file has a mime type inherently but the browser takes the file and overwrites that when sending to the server? That sounds crazy.

And how is the file extension any less spoofable than the MIME type. I am using the `accept` attribute for this check.

Comment: Reading the FileUpload docs it does seem your statement is right, which leaves me more confused. Same computer, same file and my browser is sending two different mime types?

Comment: Assuming the doc file is on the server already, what results do you get from `fileGetMimeType(path, false)` and `fileGetMimeType(path, true)`?